# C# Constant Stream pop3

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pop3

Okay so I have came to an issue that I thought I fixed with a crappy rig and it failed in the long run, so I came to ask you guys the correct way to do it. Here is the issue I have, i'm making an application to filter out a certain type of email via POP3 (using the ActiveUp api) but I need it to have a constant connection to the POP3 server...this is what I have right now:

```
public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        while(true)
        {           
            POP3();
            Console.Title = "Waiting for "+GetSubject+POST;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
    public static void POP3()
    {
        Pop3Client pop3 = new Pop3Client();
        try
        {
            pop3.ConnectSsl("pop.gmail.com",995,"", "");
            if(pop3.MessageCount > 0)
            {
                int CurrentMessage = pop3.MessageCount;
                ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message message = pop3.RetrieveMessageObject(CurrentMessage);
                if(message.Subject == GetSubject+POST)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("command reconized from {0}: {1}\n Sending responce now!",message.From.Email, message.Subject);
                SMTP (message.From.Email, _message);
                POST++;
                pop3.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no mail found"); 
            }
        }
        catch(Pop3Exception iex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(iex); 
            pop3.Close();
        }
    }
```

Everything works perfect until about 10-20 minuets of it running I get kicked off of google's POP3 server and have to restart the application...Ill run the application now and reedit my question with the error...but until then can you guys please help me? Thanks!

Error:

```
nhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
  at System.Net.Dns.hostent_to_IPHostEntry (System.String h_name, System.String[] h_aliases, System.String[] h_addrlist) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName (System.String hostName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (System.String hostNameOrAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses (System.String hostNameOrAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.String hostname, Int32 port) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Pop3Client.ConnectSsl (System.String host, Int32 port, System.String user, System.String pass, ActiveUp.Net.Security.SslHandShake sslHandShake) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Pop3Client.ConnectSsl (System.String host, Int32 port, System.String user, System.String pass) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at AutoThreadOwnerCopy.MainClass.POP3 () [0x00006] in /home/m44m31/AutoThreadOwnerCopy/AutoThreadOwnerCopy/Main.cs:35 
  at AutoThreadOwnerCopy.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00019] in /home/m44m31/AutoThreadOwnerCopy/AutoThreadOwnerCopy/Main.cs:25 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
  at System.Net.Dns.hostent_to_IPHostEntry (System.String h_name, System.String[] h_aliases, System.String[] h_addrlist) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName (System.String hostName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (System.String hostNameOrAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses (System.String hostNameOrAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.String hostname, Int32 port) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Pop3Client.ConnectSsl (System.String host, Int32 port, System.String user, System.String pass, ActiveUp.Net.Security.SslHandShake sslHandShake) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Pop3Client.ConnectSsl (System.String host, Int32 port, System.String user, System.String pass) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at AutoThreadOwnerCopy.MainClass.POP3 () [0x00006] in /home/m44m31/AutoThreadOwnerCopy/AutoThreadOwnerCopy/Main.cs:35 
  at AutoThreadOwnerCopy.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00019] in /home/m44m31/AutoThreadOwnerCopy/AutoThreadOwnerCopy/Main.cs:25
```